# How to integrate log of squared Fourier series?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, approximation

Suppose I have the square of a saw-tooth Fourier series . . . something like

$$\left(\sin(x) + \frac{\sin(2x)}{2} +\frac {\sin(3x)}{3}\right)^2$$

Is there a way to integrate the natural log of this function? I.e.,

$$\ln\left[\left(\sin(x) + \frac{\sin(2x)}{2} +\frac {\sin(3x)}{3}\right)^2\right]$$ over some interval (say, $0$ to $2\pi$)?

If the antiderivative of this is too gnarly (Mathematica spits out a pretty large antiderivative), is there a way to approximate this?

Comment: You do realize that for common functions, you can use `\function_name`, such as `\sin` or `\ln`? It helps the formatting and makes it easier to read/search.

Comment: Also, double dollar signs automatically puts things in `\displaystyle`

Answer (score 1):

Define

$$f(\theta):=\ln\left[\left(\sin(\theta)+\frac{\sin(2\theta)}2+\frac{\sin(3\theta)}3\right)^2\right]$$

$$I:=\int_0^{2\pi}f(\theta)~\mathrm d\theta$$

Unfortunately, $f(\theta)$ diverges at $\{0,\pi,2\pi\}$, but this can easily be fixed by subtracting $\ln[\sin^2(\theta)]$ from the integrand:

$$I=-4\pi\ln(2)+\int_0^{2\pi}g(\theta)~\mathrm d\theta$$

Where

$$g(\theta)=2\ln\left(\frac43+\cos(\theta)+\frac23\cos(2\theta)\right)$$

defines an analytic periodic function. Integrals of these kinds are fairly easy to approximate, as

$$\int_0^{2\pi}g(\theta)~\mathrm d\theta\approx S(n)=\frac{2\pi}n\sum_{k=1}^ng(2\pi k/n)$$

Where the error is given by the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula#The_remainder_term). The first few values for $n$ are given by

```
n      S(n)
1      13.805569180893
2       6.902784590446
3      -1.205039847179
4       0.903779885384
5       1.674257949611
6       1.095888349637
7       1.091214979992
8       1.221964856078
9       1.183137563897
10      1.163988136630
20      1.176893287973
30      1.176909709314
40      1.176909737014
50      1.176909737066
60      1.176909737067
70      1.176909737067
80      1.176909737067
90      1.176909737067
100     1.176909737067
```

And thus,

$$\begin{align}I&\dot=-4\pi\ln(2)+1.176909737067\\&\dot=-7.53343462414\end{align}$$

Comment: Two questions about your comment: First, 'Unfortunately, f(θ) diverges at  {0,π,2π}...' I presume this is due to the fact that at those values the series yields 0...and the log is undefined for this.  What if some small number (like 0.1) was added as to avoid this?

Comment: @CShreve Yes...? You can't take the log of zero, now can you?

Comment: @CShreve You could do that, but then you may as well just avoid those points like you would any improper integral

Comment: Second: could you please show how you got from $$f(\theta):=\ln\left[\left(\sin(\theta)+\frac{\sin(2\theta)}2+\frac{\sin(3\theta)}3\right)^2\right]$$ to $$g(\theta)=2\ln\left(\frac43+\cos(\theta)+\frac23\cos(2\theta)\right)$$.  Thanks

Comment: @CShreve Take $$g(\theta)=f(\theta)-\ln(\sin^2(\theta))$$And use log rules + trig identities to reduce.

Comment: Simply Beautiful Art: I don't get it.  If you are going to chop the function up into a 100 pieces for approximation...why approximate g($\theta$)? It would be easier and more accurate to just chop the original function up into 100 pieces to calculate the Reimann sum. 
 
See here - https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wwkbgxnnt6

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: @CShreve You are missing something. According to the Euler-Maclaurin formula, you will find that$$\int_0^{2\pi}f(\theta)~\mathrm d\theta=\frac{2\pi}n\sum_{k=1}^nf\left(\frac{2\pi k}n\right)+\mathcal O(1/n)$$while$$\int_0^{2\pi}g(\theta)~\mathrm d\theta=\frac{2\pi}n\sum_{k=1}^ng\left(\frac{2\pi k}n\right)+\mathcal O(1/10^{3n/10})$$

Comment: As you can see, the rate of convergence of the Riemann sum of the original function will yield 12 places accurate in $c\times10^{12}$ chops, where $c$ is some constant that isn't significant compared to the $10^{12}$. Try chopping the original into 100 pieces and Riemann summing and seeing how accurate you get.